# How to access my GrapheneDB neo4j database through Javascript alone

Tags: javascript, php, neo4j

I have a Neo4j database in GrapheneDB, and I want me and my friends to be able to create nodes and relationships from an HTML page through Javascript. I am hosting the HTML page to my server space.

This is what I tried to test node creation.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

script type="text/javascript">
    var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
    r.open("POST", "GRAPHENE REST URL", true);
    r.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200) return;
        var json_response = JSON.parse(r.responseText);
        console.log(json_response);
    };
    var cyQuery=JSON.stringify({"query" : "CREATE (ee:Person { name: 'Emil', klout: 99 })"});
    r.send(cyQuery);
</script>
```

As you can see, I tried to use REST API with Cypher but it produces the following error:

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)"

I understand that this is because I am not logged in to Graphene. 
My question is twofold:

1. can I implement loging into Graphene in the background (through PHP maybe), so that all users that access the HTML page can create a node?
2. can I do it without installing a Neo4j REST driver? I can not install programs in my server space, I can only upload files.

Thank you, I hope my question makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

1. It seems that you are not including authentication credentials in your code. GrapheneDB requires HTTP basic authentication.
2. You should be able to do this in JS. However, this is not **recommended** since anyone will be able to get your credentials, access your database, modify and delete data, etc.

If you want your users to be able to query and modify the database I suggest:

- Using a proxy or webapp to connect to the instance, thus hiding the authentication credentials from the users
- Implementing some sort of user authentication in your app so that only users who log in to your app can query/modify your database.

Comment: Thank you @albertoperdomo. Do you know how can I use a proxy or webapp to connect to the GrapheneDB instance without being seen by the user?

Comment: I do not ask for a complete tutorial, just a link to get started maybe, since I do not have experience in this.

Answer (score 0):

I did something quickly like this here.
As I was layz, I computed the base64 of username:password externally (with openssl enc base64) and provided it as a environment variable, right thing to do would be to provide both and do the encoding in node of course.

```
cat package.json 


{
  "name": "proxy-neo4j-db",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node":"0.8.26",
    "npm":"1.1.49"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node proxy"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "connect": "2.19.5",
    "http-proxy" :"1.1.4"
  }
}

cat proxy.js 


var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var connect = require('connect');

var target = { target: process.env.NEO4J_URL || process.env.GRAPHENEDB_URL || "http://localhost:7474" };
var port = process.env.PORT || 8001;
var auth = "Basic "+process.env.AUTH;

connect.createServer(
  function (req, res) {
    req.headers['Authorization']=auth;
    proxy.web(req, res);
  }
).listen(port);

var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer(target);
```